# Is there an easier way to format a string with an exact length in C#?

Tags: c#

I need to format a string to be exactly x characters, but the value I'm formatting can be any length.

```
"" => "          "
"New York" => "New York  "
"New York City" => "New York C"
```

Currently, I'm doing this:

```
$"{(address.City.Substring(0, address.City.Length > 20 ? 20 : address.City.Length)),20}"
```

Bu this becomes quite tedious and error prone the more I do:

```
var builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.AppendLine($"{(address.Street1.Substring(0, address.Street1.Length > 30 ? 30 : address.Street1.Length)),30}");
builder.AppendLine($"{(address.Street2.Substring(0, address.Street2.Length > 30 ? 30 : address.Street2.Length)),30}");
builder.AppendLine($"{(address.City.Substring(0, address.City.Length > 20 ? 20 : address.City.Length)),20}");
builder.AppendLine($"{(address.State.Substring(0, address.State.Length > 5 ? 5 : address.State.Length)),5}");
builder.AppendLine($"{(address.Zip.Substring(0, address.Zip.Length > 10 ? 10 : address.Zip.Length)),10}");
var result = builder.ToString();
```

And I have about 30 other things that I need to do this with as well. It would be really great if there was something like this:

```
address.City.SubstringExact(0, 20)
```

Comment: Check out string padding: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/padding

Comment: @WillardSolutions String padding will not truncate values that are longer than the specified length.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could just add an extension method to string, that would do that for you:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string ToLength(this string self, int length)
    {
        if(self == null)
           return null;

        return self.Length > length ? self.Substring(0, length) : self.PadRight(length);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create an extension method using padding:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string SubstringExact(this string src, int start, int length) 
    {
         return src.PadRight(start + length).Substring(start, length);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `str.PadRight(x, ' ').Substring(0, x);`

```
string str1 = "";
string res1 = str1.PadRight(10, ' ').Substring(0, 10);
// "          "
string str2 = "New York  ";
string res2 = str2.PadRight(10, ' ').Substring(0, 10);
//"New York  "
string str3 = "New York C";
string res3 = str3.PadRight(10, ' ').Substring(0, 10);
//"New York C"
```

Comment: I like this answer cause it doesn't require a extension method, but Zohar Peled's answer is more efficient.